# Test if series is convergent or divergent. Alternating series test. Am I correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have these two questions, both using the Alternating series test. Again, the test theory is here:

[image]

1) $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1} n e^{-n}$$

the first derivative that I get is $e^{-n}(1-n)$ which is negative when $n \gt 1$ so i) is a check.

ii) I use L'Hospital rule to check.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{e^n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{e^n} = 0$$

So this is convergent by AST right?

2) $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}e^{\frac{2}{n}}$$

I'm stuck on this. How do I show that the $$\lim_{n \to \infty}e^{\frac{2}{n}} = 0$$. I get that the first derivative is negative already.

Answer (score 1):

$e^{\frac{2}{n}} > 1$ for all $n > 0$, so $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} e^\frac{2}{n} \neq 0$ (and more specifically $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} e^\frac{2}{n} = 1$).